# Get errors from lambda as alert

Tags: aws-lambda, monitoring

I am investigate approaches for get errors from my lambda functions as alert by email. I want get error with text error and lambda name in email body. My functions is working as Async and Sync mode. I was used Cloud Watch but I faced with problems.

1 variant: In CW was created one alert for all functions(more then 300 and they will changed your count, not static value). This way has one big plus - all functions in my region was added and deleted from alert dynamically. But alert we will get only with common information - that we have some eror with some function.

2 variant: Set up for each function AWS Lambda Function Dead Letter Queues, and join with aws sns. In this way I have got email with errors but, it's work only with Async lambdas. And I should set up DLQ for each functions after created.

3 variant: Paid solutions (

Maybe anybody can advice me good solutions?

Comment: You should definitely have look at [thundra.io](https://thundra.io). Its free tier is more than sufficient to observe Lambda functions for development purposes. It has also an [alerting feature](https://www.thundra.io/features) which might work very well for you. (Disclaimer: I am an engineer @thundra) If you have any more questions, please do not hesitate to contact, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The way you would normally do this is by adding one alarm for every function - instead of your current setup of an alarm for all of them together.

If you were to do this manually, it's a hellish job. So consider using Cloudformation/Tropsophere/Terraform. Not only is it a good idea to version control your infrastructure, that way you can write a function/method to create and add an alarm to a lambda *once*.

The good thing is, once you have an alarm for every lambda, AWS will take care of the rest (tracking the errors and sending emails). And your message will be specific to every lambda, unlike now.

Comment: Thank you  for your response, I chose datadog for monitoring. Because I can created information dashboards, when I can see all functions with important parameters.